# direct client-to-client message

Tags: javascript, browser, client-server, chat

I have been working with node.js for a while, now when I'm looking deeper into it, for a chat aplication instead of sending message as client - server - client, there must be some possible ways for direct client to client message sending?

Comment: Are you find a WebSockets? http://socket.io/ http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets

Comment: @NiLL the way of socket.io sending message is through a server to a client, dont know if its possible to use socket.io between clients only

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032006/will-html5-allow-web-apps-to-make-peer-to-peer-http-connections

Comment: I am looking for same kind of question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809499/fire-one-website-javascript-function-from-another-without-server-side-langauge?noredirect=1#comment94467614_53809499

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browsers tend to communicate with servers via HTTP. Some implement other protocols, like websockets & [SPDY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY), but again, these are mostly client-server protocols.

Some plug-ins (like Flash & Java) can open ports and communicate client-client. (AFAIK, haven't actually used them.)

Chrome is the only browser I'm aware of that can (soon) open TCP and UDP sockets from Javascript and do direct client-client communication. At the moment normal web apps can't do this, your app needs to be run as a "Chrome Packaged App", with a special `manifest` file.

Here are the [docs](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_network.html), a [blog post](http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/chrome-tcp-udp) describing the feature and a [browserify module](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/net-chromeify) that can behave like the `net` node.js module in the browser.

EDIT: This should probably not be tagged as [node.js] since you're trying to run in browsers (not in your node vm), this is a Javascript / Browser question.

Comment: thanks for replying! So if my server is overloaded with clients therefor my first thought was sending message between clients only, seems this is not a go, would u suggest any other solution or work around?

Comment: Move as much logic as possible out of the server / split it up into multiple components that can run on multiple machines. node.js should be able to handle [many many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161796/how-many-users-nodejs-socket-io-can-support) socket.io clients at the same time, do you have more?

Comment: For people reading this after 2016, SPDY is now deprecated. Google removed SPDY support in Google Chrome 51. Mozilla removed it in Firefox 50.[8] Apple has deprecated the technology in macOS 10.14.4 and iOS 12.2.

Answer (score 2):

This is maybe out of date question, but take a look on [PeerJS](http://peerjs.com/).

It requires server only as a connection manager (broker). But all communication is done between clients directly.

Answer (score 1):

This does not have anything with server. If you need something like that and if clients are flash you can use [RTMFP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Media_Flow_Protocol) . For JS i google this [library](https://github.com/HoLyVieR/RTMFP-JS-Bridge#readme) which is js bridge for RTMFP, I dont know how it works. At the end you can write you own library to chat beetween clients but this is much harder(IP addresses are  behind NAT, etc...)

Comment: how come it does nothing with server? the server has to start a client, and when a 2nd client is started, there should be a way of sending message between the two clients only

Comment: Sorry, I didnt ment initial chat does not require server, but chat between two clients later(if you do not want to go through server) does not. Maybe I wasnt clear enough. Anyway if you are able to use flash/flex then go out with RTMFP. Chat roulette is made that way

Comment: ty for cleaning up, so what u suggest is about real time IO if I didnt missunderstand? Then do you know about nowjs https://github.com/Flotype/now ? Maybe its a solution too?

Comment: That doesnt look to me like valid pear to pear socket library, it looks like some kind of framework based on express and I suppose it is meant for rapid web application developing. Communication clinet-server and client-client is very different because, for start, client always knows server IP address

Answer (score 0):

I think answer for your question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022383/how-to-make-a-browser-to-browser-peer-to-peer-connection)

PS Also exist open-source in-browser server which written using JS, but I didn't google it quickly. If you find it, please notify me.

Answer (score 0):

If you just don't want to write your own server you can use:

https://httprelay.io

Use AJAX calls to communicate between peers.