# Performance comparison of websocket implementations

Tags: node.js, performance, websocket

**EDIT:** to prevent closing this question I'll just narrow it down to the essential.

> Can someone share a performance test in MB/s between the two websocket implementations listed below? Application or hardware details are irrelevant, just two crude numbers for a simple common scenario will suffice.

---

**Original question**

Did someone test the performance of these two websocket implemetations for *node.js*?

- [WebSocket-Node](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node)
- [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws)

I couldn't find anything recent (just a bunch of articles from 2012-2013). What I would like to see is:

- overhead (if at all, considering that actual *network* latency is more relevant I guess they both converge to 0)
- throughput (a simple MB/S figure for same application/hardware would be great)
- can *ws* really **broadcast** data on a network level (despite an underlying TCP? is this at all possible?) or is it just an abused method name (which actually sends the same message to many clients in a `for()` loop)?

Even better:

- comparison of with/without Nagle's algorithm
- comparison of JSON vs binary messages

Comment: Why not run various tests locally and find out?

Comment: @mscdex yes, that's exactly what I'm asking for: if someone did it already and can share it with the community.

Comment: Server side webSocket sends data on already connected webSocket connections which runs on top of a TCP socket.  The phrase "broadcast" probably means to send a certain piece of data to multiple endpoints that currently have a connected webSocket.  There is no ability to broadcast outside of a currently connected webSocket connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** updated with info about a newer, faster implementation

I integrate here **NiCk Newman**'s *Jun 17 '16 at 20:08* comment to avoid it from getting lost by any means.

A newer and faster implementation of websockets is [uWS](http://github.com/alexhultman/uWebSockets). Promising results are reported by several devs. For simple cases it's almost a no-brainer. The below discussion is therefore somewhat superseded.

---

I wonder why nobody could answer this question. So, after even more hours of search then I've done before I finally came to this page where some answers are given.

I post it here and answer my own question so that others searching for it find it easier.

The page is the [benchmark comparison of ws](https://web.archive.org/web/20151030054533/http://einaros.github.io/ws/benchmarks.html). Yes, it's pretty straightforward but it's somehow buried away.

Here are the relevant results:

In my case I want to send 4-16KB JSON messages (even 4KB is an exaggeration, most messages will be just 100-200 characters). The first graph shows that for up to 64KB there's no appreciable difference at all. Only for larger messages (around 16MB) it becomes increasingly evident that ws is faster than websocket-node.

For binary messages, both are the same (if not identical). This makes me wonder if they somehow borrowed code from each other on GitHub. Which would be nice btw as both *ARE* on GitHub to be shared and forked and so on.

The following graphs show message fragmentation, which is relevant for streaming, but I'm not interested in it. So the above answers my question:

> 1. performance is identical for non-fragmented text messages (up to 16MB)
> 2. performance is identical for non-fragmented binary messages (no size limit)

Comment: Hmm, do you know what the server specs were when that test was done? Really interesting!

Comment: I couldn't find anything about specs, but I guess it is just a rough comparison. All implementations should benefit in a comparable way from better hardware/native platform implementation. Precise measurements in real-world scenarios would have so many moving parts that a synthetic benchmark is probably more useful anyways.

Comment: I would like to see a `ws` test done on 1 nodejs server measuring concurrency (100+ players connected, sending packets back and forth), and see what kind of server can handle that. And know when it's time to start scaling.

Comment: Me too :) As far as I can tell, JSON parse/stringify should be avoided for high frequency messages. Better rely on a fixed-size 64KB  ByteArray which batches all data into one binary block. Low frequency messages (less than once per 4-5 seconds) can still go over JSON as long as they're not too large (under 16KB). Don't look at the numbers, they are wild guesses, but understand the reasoning on how to optimize network code. How many players can then be supported? I have no idea, only real-world measurements on AWS or other cloud providers can tell.

Comment: I found a very useful [benchmark](https://bocoup.com/weblog/node-stress-test-analysis/) yesterday,  and it also coincides with this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12388147/1254837). Of around 1,300 concurrent users each instance sending/receiving messages.   This is the closest and most realistic data I can find, if you can find others please let me know. For the first benchmark, I just don't know what server specs were on the EC2.

Comment: Just to add, https://github.com/alexhultman/uWebSockets runs laps around `ws`. The dev from wilds.io said he went from 40 players per droplet (running ws) too now over 200 by switching to `uWS`.

Comment: The 2nd link is down.

Comment: That's sad. But luckily I summarized the findings in the answer. Also consider that 2 years have passed and that this info may not be relevant anymore.